# Reverse looping scroll background actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to reverse the direction of a scrolling background in flash using actionscript.

I thought if I just changed the `BG1.y-=10` to `BG1.y+=10` that would do the trick but it seems to break the `if` statement and the backgound no longer loops.

Can anyone give me some directions on where things are going wrong?

```
function scroll(evt:Event):void
       {
        BG1.y-=10;
        BG2.y-=10;
        if(currentBG.y<-currentBG.height)
           {
               if(currentBG==BG1)
               {
                   BG1.y=BG2.y+BG2.height;
                   currentBG=BG2;
               }
               else
               {
                   BG2.y=BG1.y+BG1.height;
                   currentBG=BG1;
               }
           }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the code that makes this scroll. Is there an ENTER_FRAME loop that's driving that? Could you show more code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct in assuming your if statement will no longer work if you change the iteration to a positive increment of 10. To update your if statement to handle both cases you simply need to determine which direction you are scrolling in and adjust accordingly. So for this you can create a variable as **@Rajneesh** has done, but implement your if statements differently. Here's what that would look like:

```
private function scroll( e:Event ):void {
    BG1.y += scrollSpeed;
    BG2.y += scrollSpeed;

    if ( currentBG.y < -currentBG.height && scrollSpeed < 0 ) {
        currentBG.y += currentBG.height;
        currentBG = currentBG == BG2 ? BG1 : BG2;
    }
    else if ( currentBG.y >= currentBG.height && scrollSpeed > 0 ) {
        currentBG.y -= currentBG.height;
        currentBG = currentBG == BG2 ? BG1 : BG2;
    }
}
```

I've slightly adjusted your if statements to make the code more condensed, but it is doing the same thing.

So if our `scrollSpeed` is negative we will check:

```
if ( currentBG.y < -currentBG.height && scrollSpeed < 0 )
```

We have determined that we are scrolling in a **negative** direction and should adjust the `currentBG` y value accordingly. **Else**:

```
else if ( currentBG.y >= currentBG.height && scrollSpeed > 0 )
```

We are scrolling in a **positive** direction and should re-position the `currentBG`, subtracted by its height.

If you are unfamiliar with the ternary operation `?` as in the statements:

```
currentBG = currentBG == BG2 ? BG1 : BG2;
```

this is saying the same thing as an if/else statement:

```
if ( currentBG == BG1 ) {
    currentBG = BG2;
} else {
    currentBG = BG1;
}
```